# My time calculation gives me a minus figure

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core

The following works fairly well:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace cursor_position
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;;
            TimeSpan timeRemaining;
            int intCount = 119;
            
            for (int i = 0; i <= intCount; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                
                Console.Clear();

                timeRemaining = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).Ticks * (intCount - (i+1)) / (i+1));

                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                Console.Write("ETA: ");
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0} Minutes, {1} Seconds", timeRemaining.Minutes, timeRemaining.Seconds));

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, right at the end, I get a minus figure for the ETA calculation.  The longer the code runs (if I increase the `sleep` or the `intCount`) the larger the ETA minus figure becomes.

Anyone know why?

Comment: This is because larger the time delay, larger the Ticks with is multiplied by  -1 (consider the case where i=59 your time remaining get calculated by Ticks*(59-60)/60 ).

Comment: Why don't you just count down by seconds?

Comment: I'd consider using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive") - then you can just do this: `DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now; DateTime targetTime = startTime.AddMinutes(1.0); var query = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).Select(x => targetTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now)); query.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"ETA: {x.Minutes} Minutes, {x.Seconds} Seconds"));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always problematic when you try to compute time differences using maths like that. It's better to harden your code against it by not using a counter at all.

Try this code:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime targetTime = startTime.AddMinutes(1.0);

while (true)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    if (now > targetTime)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        TimeSpan timeRemaining = targetTime.Subtract(now);

        Console.Write("ETA: ");
        Console.Write(String.Format("{0} Minutes, {1} Seconds", timeRemaining.Minutes, timeRemaining.Seconds));

        Console.WriteLine();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

---

I think the use of `Thread.Sleep(1000)` (in your original question) and `Thread.Sleep(2000)` in your current one made it unclear to me that you want to compute the remaining time of a indeterminate process, such as copying a file. It seemed to me you were just doing a "timer countdown".

Let's write a general purpose function for estimated the remaining time of an indeterminate process.

```
public TimeSpan ComputeRemaining((int count, DateTime time) start, (int count, DateTime time) current, int end) =>
    current.count - start.count == 0
        ? TimeSpan.MaxValue
        : TimeSpan.FromSeconds((end - current.count) * current.time.Subtract(start.time).TotalSeconds / (current.count - start.count));
```

Given a starting count and `DateTime`, a given `current` count and `DateTime`, along with the desired `end` count, this function produces the time remaining.

It can work with the count going up or down.

Let see it in action.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var start = (count: 0, time: now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)));
var current = (count: 50, time: now);
var end = 100;
Console.WriteLine(ComputeRemaining(start, current, end).TotalSeconds);
```

So the example is a process that started `5.0` seconds ago and it is now 50% complete - how long will it take? `5.0` seconds to go. This code correctly writes out `5`.

Let's try it with your sample app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var random = new Random();
    
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    int intCount = 30;

    for (int i = 0; i <= intCount; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(random.Next(100, 2000));

        TimeSpan timeRemaining = ComputeRemaining((0, startTime), (i, DateTime.Now), intCount);

        Console.Write("ETA: ");
        Console.Write(String.Format("{0} Minutes, {1} Seconds", timeRemaining.Minutes, timeRemaining.Seconds));

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
ETA: 48 Minutes, 5 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 54 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 39 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 42 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 41 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 33 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 32 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 32 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 31 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 29 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 29 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 28 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 27 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 25 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 22 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 20 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 18 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 17 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 16 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 14 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 12 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 11 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 10 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 8 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 7 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 6 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 4 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 3 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 2 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 1 Seconds
ETA: 0 Minutes, 0 Seconds
```

Note that in the early stages of my example the estimate actually increased as it was being computed from a random input of time.

I trust that this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Not sure how I can apply this to my code as I do not know how long it will take to finish beforehand.

Comment: @oshirowanen - Yes, you do. You're setting `intCount` and you have `Thread.Sleep(X)` You know you're computing `intCount * X` milliseconds forward.

Comment: @oshirowanen - Oh, is this meant to be a moving estimate? Is this like when you move a file it shows an estimated time until the move is completed? So the use of `Thread.Sleep(2000);` is just to simulate work?

Comment: @oshirowanen - Is this the kind of thing you're trying to calculate? What is exactly what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have parenthesis problem.

Suppose that we have set `intCount = 1`, so based on your code, the `for` loop will be executed twice. once for `i=0` and once for `i=1`.

When `i = 0` we have: `1234 * (intCount - (i + 1)) / (i + 1) ==> 1234*(1 - (0 + 1)) / (0 + 1)`

Above code is equal to `1234 * A / B`, where A is `(intCount - (i + 1))` and B is `(i + 1)`. So first `1234 * A` will be calculated and then the result will be divided to B!

So we have `1234 * (1-(0+1))` which is equal to 0 and then `0 / 1` which is equal to 0.

When `i = 1` we have `1234 * (intCount - (i + 1)) / (i + 1) ==> 1234*(1 - (1 + 1)) / (1 + 1)  = -617

we have `1234 * (1-(1+1))` which is equal to -1234 and then `-1234 / 1` which is equal to -1234.

To solve this problem you need to change the `for` loop as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < intCount; i++)
```

In this case the loop will be executed once(`i=0`) and you will not get minus value anymore. and also do this modification to solve the parenthesis problem too:

```
timeRemaining = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).Ticks * ((intCount - (i + 1)) / (i + 1)));
```

Comment: You have your maths wrong. `-1 / 2 == 0`. If it were `-1.0 / 2.0` then that would equal `-0.5`, but not with integers.

Comment: @Enigmativity you are right, I have updated the answer

Comment: The maths is still wrong. When you have `ticks = 1234`, `intCount = 1`, and `i = 1`, then `(ticks * (intCount - (i + 1)) / (i + 1)) == -617`. You're on the right track but you're showing some confusing numbers. And you're showing a doubly confusing `-0.5` still.

Comment: What a careless I am:-|